# Typescript uitility type that makes the property optional but doesn't set value to a union with undefined

Tags: typescript, type-systems

The utility type `Partial<>` doesn't just set the keys of a type to optional, but their values to a union with undefined:

```
type Obj = { foo: number }
type PartialObj = Partial<Obj> // { foo?: number | undefined }
```

Does a utility type exist that would instead result in: `{ foo?: number }`

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

> Does a utility type exist that would instead result in: `{ foo?: number }`?

A utility type does not exist for that.

Why? TypeScript sees `{ foo?: number }` and `{ foo?: number | undefined }` as the same type.

## Some Exploration

Here are the hover result in VS Code, which show that both types have the same result.

[image]

In some ways, this makes sense, because a non-existent property equals `undefined`. Here, the `obj1` does not have the `foo` property, and yet the `foo` property is triple equal to `undefined`.

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {
  foo: undefined
};

console.log(obj1.foo === undefined);
console.log(obj2.foo === undefined);
```

That said, an object with a non-existent property *does* differ from an object with that property set to `undefined`. In the following, the console outputs something different for `obj1` and `obj2`.

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {
  foo: undefined
};

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

So it the type system "wrong"? Should there be a way to say, "The property needs to be a number or nothing at all... not even undefined." Maybe yes, maybe no; be sure the answer is full of complexities.

JavaScript is a language with lots of warts, and TypeScript does its best to represent it - warts and all - in static types. The resultant type system is not "sound", [nor does it try to be](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals).